# Create new wordpress theme with no need update

Tags: theme-development

I want to make a customize site for my client. I want to use wordpress and I no have basic in wordpress develop, so I plan to override some code on twenty thirteen. Some question in my head about my planning:

1. Can I override some code on Twenty Thirteen, and use different name folder and stylesheet? Is right of law?
2. If I rename n create customize TT theme, how about the update of theme? Because I want to one time develop and no support or update for theme, is the theme  secure?

Any suggest to me please?

Comment: Questions are meant to be references for later visitors as well. Please rework your questions spelling/punctuation/grammar/capitalization so it as as easy to read as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never change any file or code within a theme. Nearly all theme get updated by their authors, and you will loose all your customizations. That said, twenty thirteen, and for that matter, all default themes that come shipped with Wordpress are excellent basis to create your own child theme. Even when twenty thirteen gets updated (which it definitly will), you will not loose your customization.

To create a child theme is extremely easy. Just create a new folder in wp-content, call it what you like, create a stylesheet.css file inside the folder and add the following to your stylesheet

```
   /*
 Theme Name:   Put the name of your theme here
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/Put-the-name-of-your-theme-here/
 Description:  Twenty Thirteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     twentythirteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
   */

@import url("../twentythirteen/style.css");

/* =Theme customization starts here
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

and your done

Go and read more on child themes and how to do customizations [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Comment: Pieter:Great Idea, use child theme. Could i use folder with name `ghosttheme` not `twentythirteen-child` ? Its legal?

Comment: You can change everything to your linking, except the `@import` part and `Template` part. These must stay intact so the child theme will now which parent to use. For great tutorials about child themes, do a simple google search. There are plenty to have a look at. Please remember to accept my awnswer

Comment: Pieter : One question again, If we override (lets say) class `.footerbg` on Twenty Thirteen latest version. Can developer wordpress use that class again in next version (when update in future)? If not use class `.footerbg` again so my override not work. What usually update by developer wordpress about the theme Twenty Thirteen?